# How to form an "international alliance of nationalists"?

Tags: warfare, politics, military-organisation

We know the joke about having "flat-earther all over the globe" and "international alliances of nationalists". But how to set the latter up in reality? How to make these people, who think they are protecting their own country/ethnic's rights, interests, and prestige form a paramilitary organization with a known enemy powerful enough to threaten the globalization status quo? How do nationalists of different and opposing nations fight side by side on the battlefield to upend the current world order knowing that they will instantly turn on each other the moment the current world order ends?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133493/discussion-on-question-by-faito-dayo-how-to-form-an-international-alliance-of-n).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the European parliament. Sovranist leaders like Orban, Salvini, Farage, each of them campaigning against the union and for their own national interest, have had no problem in jointly acting.

What matters is that one has to twist the propaganda in such a way that there is a common interest, visible and clear, to act as a glue between the parts.

It is what happened during both World Wars, for example, where the fight against the evil other side put together apparently opposing interests, like imperial Britain with self deterministic USA and communist USSR, or the different racial suprematists of Japan, Germany and Italy.